# Run debug scripts in 32-bit in VbsEdit

Tags: vbscript, debug, 32-vs-64-bit

I use a 64-bit [VbsEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/) on my Windows 7 computer to debug my VBScript code.

Sometimes I need to run the scripts in 32-bit mode (C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wscript.exe).

Can I force VbsEdit to use the 32-bit script engine?

Comment: Try to launch it from a 32-bit command prompt by running `%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe`. If this works, you may create a desktop shortcut for it that uses cmd with the `/c` parameter.

Comment: I just saw that VbsEdit seemed to have installed a 64-bit **and** also a 32-bit version. Running the 32-bit version of VbsEdit works - it uses the 32-bit VB runtime.

Comment: My above comment was made in order to help find out if a 32-bit version exists for VbsEdit. Was it useful for that?

Comment: It was.........

Comment: I have incorporated it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use VbsEdit, but in an attempt to discover if it has a 32-bit version,
I have asked the poster to launch it from a 32-bit Command Prompt
(`%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe`).

The poster has reported that such a version does exist, so is now able
to launch directly the 32-bit executable or to continue to use
it from the 32-bit Command Prompt.